# localStorage not saving changed radio button values if "checked" is used

Tags: javascript, radio-button, local-storage, default, checked

Tried to solve this multiple ways.  1. by simply adding the normal html "checked" default option to radio buttons in my form and 2. having js functions do it, being the gist of the ideas tried.

The issue:  I'm finding that no matter how I do it, if the radio is designated as checked by default (before the user makes his/her choice), anything done after that will not be saved correctly (if at all) in localStorage. localStorage WILL save the initial default selections, however but, nothing can be changed from then on (even after "physically" selecting another option).

I know localStorage is working because if I leave off the default designation (and for the rest of the inputs) it functions perfectly.

The form code:

```
<label>Who is the contact person for this event?<span class="requiredtext">*</span></label>
<input type="radio" name="Contact_Person" id="Contact_Person1" value="Submitter is the contact person" onclick="contacthide()" checked required>&nbsp;I am<br />
<input type="radio" name="Contact_Person" id="Contact_Person2" value="Submitter is not the contact person" onclick="contactshow()" required>
```

The localStorage save code:

```
function localStoragefunctions() {
    localStorage.clear();
    if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
        //Set variable to show that data is saved
        localStorage.setItem("flag", "set");

        //Save radio and checkbox data
        $(window).bind('unload', function() {
            $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
                localStorage.setItem('radio_' + $(this).attr('id'), JSON.stringify({ 
                    checked: this.checked
                }));
            });
        });
```

The code that spits it back out if the user goes back to make changes before final submission:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if (Modernizr.localstorage) {
            //Browser supports it
            if (localStorage.getItem("flag") == "set") {

$('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
                    var state = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('radio_' + $(this).attr('id')));
                    if (state) this.checked = state.checked;
                });
```

Other than this, I have a confirmation page that grabs all of the variables stored in localStorage and presents them to the user for final inspection before they hit submit for good.

That consists of:  `var ContactPerson = localStorage.getItem('Contact_Person');` and then a `document.write` that spits out html and the variable's value. Again, this works fine if I don't try to set default radio choices (and works great for all other input types).

The ideal outcome would be choosing the most likely radio button choices by default so that it could possibly save the user time.  I'd like to not have to present them with a form where they have to physically click each radio button if I can "make that decision for them" before hand.

Hope this all makes sense!

Comment: Rather than wait for the `window unload` event, you could try updating the localStorage as the form is updated (via `input onlick` events, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I know this an old question, but I've been troubleshooting a similar issue and thought I'd share my solution.

When you set your localStorage item, you are saving both radio inputs and their values, b/c your using the ID attribute as your key.

```
localStorage.setItem('radio_' + $(this).attr('id'), JSON.stringify({ checked: this.checked }));
```

This could be ok, but I've taken a different approach. And, I maybe missing something, so comments are welcome.

Instead, I use `$(this).attr('name')` to set the key. As a result, when either radio button in selected, you are saving the value to the same localStorage key.

In my scenario, I'm storing many inputs to localStorage, so my solution is a bit abstract. I'm calling saveToLocalStorage() using jQuery's .change() method on each input. Also, I'm saving the input's value directly to localStorage.

```
function saveToLocalStorage(input) {
  if ( $(input).attr('type')=='radio' ) {
    localStorage[$(input).attr('name')] = $(input).val();
  } else {
    localStorage[$(input).attr('id')] = $(input).val();
  }
}
```

When retrieving from localStorage, I had to check if the localStorage key:value pair matched the radio input before selecting it. Otherwise, I was selecting both radio inputs. Note, in my scenario, I'm working with jQuery 1.4.4, hence the attr('checked', 'checked').

```
$('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
  var key = $(this).attr('name');
  var val = localStorage[key];
  if ( $(this).attr('name') == key && $(this).attr('value') == val ) {
    $(this).attr('checked', 'checked');
  }
});
```